# Exclude parameters taken from XML by regular expression (regex)

Tags: powershell

I have a parameter in XML files with a mask:

```
<id>ALL2-20210301-XXXXXX-XXXXX_X</id>
```

where ALL2 is always the same parameter, 20210301 is a date so changing every day, and XXXXXX-XXXXX_X is a variable parameter.

I want to parse XML and get **20210304** value (or other date) with regex - I don't need any other parameter from . How should regular expression value looks like?

code is:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content c:\buy\buy.xml
$date= $xml.buy.id[0]
if ($date -match "regex?") {
    $date = $matches[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex, you can just split on '-' and take the second element, so for example:

`$result = ($date -split '-')[1]`

It is likely faster than regex too (haven't measured).

Answer (score 1):

Several alternative approaches

```
$date = 'ALL2-20210301-XXXXXX-XXXXX_X'

$date.Split('-')[1]

$date -split '-' | Select-Object -Index 1

$date -replace '^.+?-|-.+$'

$date -replace '.+(\d{8}).+','$1'

[regex]::Match($date,'\d{8}').Value

if($date -match '\d{8}'){$matches.0}
```